# Dividir data (dia, mês, ano) em novas colunas - DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um `DataFrame` e precisava dar um `split` no campo de data dele pra posteriormente adicionar colunas de mês e dia.

O problema é que o campo `data` do DataFrame não é do tipo `str`, portanto, não consigo utilizar o método `split`.

**Estrutura do DataFrame**

```
data        usuarios
2018-01-01  215.0
```

**Objetivo**

```
data          usuarios      ano      mes
2018-01-01    215.0         2018     01
```

**Tentativas**

```py
# df.data.apply(str)
# df["data"].apply(str)
# df["data"].astype(basestring)
df.data.str.split("-")
```

Já tentei dessas formas mas nenhuma delas resolveu o meu problema.

Tentei também utilizando a [documentação oficial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) mas também não consegui solucioná-lo.

**Erro Exibido**

> AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: você poderia marcar uma das respostas como aceita. Entenda importância disso nesse link: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `lambda` para transformar a variável de data em `string` e depois usar o slicing para selecionar a parte da data que você quer. No seu caso:

```
df['ano'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:4])
df['mes'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[5:7])
```

Um exemplo replicável:

```
import pandas as pd

#criando um banco de exemplo
df = pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016]*30, 
'month': [2, 3]*30,'day': [4, 5]*30}, 
index = range(60))).to_frame().join(pd.DataFrame({'dados': range(60)}, 
index = range(60)))
df.columns = ['data', 'dados']


#Criando as colunas de ano e mês
df['ano'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:4])
df['mes'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[5:7])

print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
        data  dados   ano mes
0 2015-02-04      0  2015  02
1 2016-03-05      1  2016  03
2 2015-02-04      2  2015  02
3 2016-03-05      3  2016  03
4 2015-02-04      4  2015  02
```

Answer (score 3):

Este erro acontece porque sua coluna `data` não é do tipo `str`, e sim do tipo `datetime64`. Para ver os tipos das colunas do seu Data Frame, basta fazer

```
>>> df.dtypes
data        datetime64[ns]
usuarios           float64
```

Para pegar o ano e o mês de uma coluna `datetime`, basta fazer:

```
df['ano'] = df['data'].dt.year
df['mes'] = df['data'].dt.month
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,
Acredito que a forma mais simples de fazer seja convertendo a data para datetime no pandas.
No caso do seu código não está claro mas acredito que seja Ano-Mês-Dia, caso não seja é só reorganizar no código abaixo:

```
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(chamadosClientes['data'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Depois disso você coloca as partes que deseja em uma nova coluna

```
df['ano']  = df['data'].dt.strftime('%Y')
df['mes'] = df['data'].dt.strftime('%m')
```

Caso deseje no futuro colocar em algum gráfico por mês no ano, pode ser feito usando mais de um valor no código

```
df['mes_ano'] = df['data'].dt.strftime('%m-%Y')
```

Acredito que assim fique mais lógico e fácil de manipular, já que você pode extrair a informação específica e reordenar como preferir, dd/mm/aaaa ou mm/dd/aaaa.